# while loop works without condition

Tags: python, while-loop, do-while

As far as I know, while statement requires condition to work, but here it works without any; how's that possible? How does `while q:` work?

The code is below:
...

```
q = set([])
for i in range(N):
    q.add((i, 0))
    q.add((i, M - 1))
    w[i][0] = h[i][0]
    w[i][M - 1] = h[i][M - 1]
for i in range(M):
    q.add((0, i))
    q.add((N - 1, i))
    w[0][i] = h[0][i]
    w[N - 1][i] = h[N - 1][i]

while q:
    ci, cj = q.pop()
    for ii, jj in ((0, 1), (0, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 0)):
        ni, nj = ci + ii, cj + jj
        if 0 <= ni < N and 0 <= nj < M:
            if w[ni][nj] != h[ni][nj] and (w[ni][nj] is None or w[ni][nj] > w[ci][cj]):
                w[ni][nj] = max(h[ni][nj], w[ci][cj])
                q.add((ni, nj))
```

Comment: Problem unclear

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `while` loop evaluates any expression it is given as a boolean. Pretty much everything in Python has a boolean value. Empty containers, such as `set()` generally evaluate to `False`, while non-empty containers, such as a set with at least one element, evaluate to `True`.

`while q:` can therefore be read as "loop while `q` is not empty", i.e., "loop as long as `q` does not evaluate to boolean `False`".

As an aside, instances of any class you write will usually evaluate to `True`. You can modify this by implementing a `__bool__` method in your class that returns something else.

Also, `q = set()` works fine. No need for `q = set([])`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's not quite obvious (very non-obvious, to be honest), and  python documentation wasn't helpful in this case.

Comment: Dunno. I thought that https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement was pretty clear, but I do understand that it is pretty technical for a beginner unfamiliar with the terminology.

Answer (score 1):

There is a condition. 
The loop will iterate as long as there is an element in set q.

You would get a similar effect if you wrote:

```
while len(q):
    # do something
```

or even

```
while len(q) > 0:
    #do something
```

However, these expressions could be viewed as perhaps a little redundant.